# Why don't pytest fixtures work as intended?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, fixtures, pytest

I'm trying to use PyTest and I cannot obtain how to set fixtures. I've tried the following code:

```
import pytest
import random

@pytest.fixture()
def setup():
    a = random.randint(0, 10)

def test(setup):
    assert 3 > a
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pytest.main()
```

And I am getting `"NameError: name 'a' is not defined".`

Also the example from the official documentation doesn't work. What's wrong? I need functionality similar to **setUp/tearDown**. But I don't want to use *unittest*. Can someone provide me an example with working fixtures (both setUp type and tearDown type)?

I want to write some test as functions and some test as methods inside classes. Therefore me second question is for an working example of using fixture with classes/methods. I just need to see working examples of fixtures in Python.

Is there a different **Python 3** unit testing framework with assertions as simple as in **PyTest**?

Answer (score 8):

Fixtures don’t work like this. They cannot magically transfer the name `a` from one function’s (`setup`) local scope to another’s (`test`). Instead, your `setup` function must explicitly return the object that will be passed as the `setup` argument to your `test` function. For example:

```
import pytest
import random

class TestSetup:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = random.randint(0, 10)

@pytest.fixture()
def setup():
    return TestSetup()

def test(setup):
    assert 0 <= setup.a <= 10

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pytest.main()
```

Comment: Thanks **Vasiliy**. Is there a easier way to setUp/tearDown with pytest? By easier I mean less typing. I'v tried to define variable in fixture and return it, but it doesn't work. I really don't want to define additional class for this. Any advice would be helpful. And again, is there another unit testing framework with assertions defined with statements as in pytest? I want to write as little as possible:) Thanks again.

Comment: @master.py If you only need one variable (`a` in this case), just `return` it from `setup()`. Then, inside `test()`, the value of the `setup` parameter will be the value you returned, so you can write: `assert 0 <= setup <= 10`.

Comment: **Vasiliy**! it works. And it is simple. I was confused by documentation. I have two more favors to ask. Can you show me how to set tearDown in similar way - I've read docs and I have no idea :( And how to set default setUp and tearDown for all tests without explicitly putting something like 'def test(setup): '

Comment: @master.py The docs are really clear, see [fixture finalization](http://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html#fixture-finalization-executing-teardown-code) (`request.addfinalizer`) and [autouse fixtures](http://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html#autouse-fixtures-xunit-setup-on-steroids) (`autouse=True`).

Comment: Vasiliy it doesn't work for me, but I can workaround this issue. Please tell me one last thing how to set fixture (setUp type) for many tests. I'm trying to avoid things like **def testa(setup):**, **def testb(setup):** and so on I'm studying docs and nothing - perhaps I'm stupid, perhaps I need more examples.

Comment: @master.py As I said, [autouse fixtures](http://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html#autouse-fixtures-xunit-setup-on-steroids).

Answer (score 1):

More typically you'd do something like:

```
/usr/bin/env python
import pytest
import random

@pytest.fixture()
def my_rand_int():
    return random.randint(0,10)

def test(my_rand_int):
    assert 3 > my_rand_int

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pytest.main()
```